# Python: Check if strings in list match very specific conditions

Tags: python, string, list, python-re, findall

I have a list of file name strings similar to this (but very long):

`list = ['AB8372943.txt', 'test.pdf', '123485940.docx', 'CW2839502.txt', 'AB1234567.txt', '283AB.txt']`

I am looking to make another list out of this one by taking only the strings that match 4 conditions:

1. Start with substring "AB"
2. End with substring ".txt"
3. Between "AB" and ".txt" there must be any 7 digit number
4. There are no other substrings in the string (i.e only the 3 items above can be in the string)

Therefore in this case the desired result would be this list:

`list2 = ['AB8372943.txt', 'AB1234567.txt']`

So far I know that to check for a 7 digit number I can use:

`list2 = [i for i in list if re.findall(r"\d{7}", i)]`

And how to look for substrings within the strings... But it isn't enough for the strings to just contain the substrings, they need to start and end with a specific one and have a 7 digit number in the middle and that's it! Is there a way to do this???

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To also make sure it starts with `AB` and ends with `.txt`:

```py
my_list = ['AB8372943.txt', 'test.pdf', '123485940.docx', 'CW2839502.txt', 'AB1234567.txt', '283AB.txt']
my_list2 = [i for i in my_list if re.findall(r"^AB\d{7}.txt$", i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a built in name like `list`. Also, if the string does not contain sub strings, you can use `re.match` which will start the match from the start of the string.

```
AB\d{7}\.txt\Z
```

The pattern matches:

- `AB\d{7}` Match AB and 7 digits
- `\.txt` Match `.txt` and note to escape the dot
- `\Z` End of string

For example

```
import re

lst = ['AB8372943.txt', 'test.pdf', '123485940.docx', 'CW2839502.txt', 'AB1234567.txt', '283AB.txt']
lst2 = [s for s in lst if re.match(r"AB\d{7}\.txt\Z", s)]
print(lst2)
```

Output

```
['AB8372943.txt', 'AB1234567.txt']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ln3feA)